# QueryString drops all but one field-value pair

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect, query-string

G'day all.

Running into a bit of an issue and I can't seem to find any solutions for it whatsoever. I've searched around and even re-read the Query string article on wikipedia and relearnt the structure of query strings to no avail.

Here's the issue.

I have a website (`www.example.com`) and I have an application on my computer that's run on a network with an Outlook Mail Server. The application, on clicking a button, sends an email to all parties selected and within that is a link to the website for a yes/no option. So there are two hyperlink buttons:

`<a href="www.example.com/Login.aspx?r=www.example.com/test?user=ID&selection=yes">YES</a>`

**AND**

`<a href="www.example.com/Login.aspx?r=www.example.com/test?user=ID&selection=no">NO</a>`

Now when they get sent to their respective browsers the querystring comes up perfectly. The moment they login, however, it removes the trailing querystrings leaving only "www.example.com/test?user=ID" in the address bar.

Any idea on how to keep the trailing query strings? Or what could possibly be causing this? The websites code clearly states to redirect to the url specified - which it 'sort of' does.

VB Code behind:

```
    If Not (Request.QueryString("r") Is Nothing) Then
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString("r"))
    End If
```

See, simple enough... but yet I run into this issue and it's annoying me that it could be something so simple.

Cheers for any help.

EDIT:

For anyone that may run into this issue and finds that URL Encoding doesn't work - Try URL decoding after pulling the full string with a little function similar to what @Frank_Vr posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23772792/3296133). Works like a charm for me now. Cheers to both Mr Moose & Frank_Vr!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be wise to encode that query string.

See the examples for [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Snippet below for quick reference;

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string destinationURL = "http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx?user=test";

        NextPage.NavigateUrl = "~/Finish?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(destinationURL);
    }             
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I've read through the MSDN documentation and this is seeming to be what I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No probs. Glad it has helped you out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

because you have two question marks the Request.querystring will split it there, try using the following:

```
    Dim url As String = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do Until i = url.length
    i = i + 1
    If mid(ucase(url), i, 2) = "R=" Then
     Response.Redirect(mid(URL,i+2)
    End If
    Loop
```

Comment: I tried this one first, unfortunately I hit a massive head block and couldn't get the remainder of it to be the URL. Cheers for the help anyhow, greatly appreciated! +1

Answer (score 1):

A question mark signals the beginning of a Query string, all parameters after the initial one are separated by an '&'. You have two question marks, which is causing the query string parser to give you an incorrect array.

Comment: Completely omitted that second question mark! Thanks for pointing this out. However I do require it in the query string - but it solves the answer as to why the query string is dropping the last field-value pairs! Cheers! +1